# how to write a update statement in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I just did my very first steps in plsql. I want to loop over all tables and change a certain field if it has a certain old value. 
Unfortunately I don’t really know, how to escape my values in my update statement and get an error message.

> "syntax error at or near "=" at line16",

which is the following line:

```
execute 'update xyz.' || info || 'set 
 update_date = 2010-11-17 17:00:00 where update_date =2010-11-16 17:00:00';
```

---

```
create or replace function test() returns text as $$

declare 
re text default '';
info text;
cur_tables cursor for select  table_name FROM 
information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'xyz';
begin

open cur_tables;

fetch next from cur_tables into info;

while (found) loop
        re := re|| ',' ||info;

    execute 'update xyz.' || info 
  || 'set update_date = 2010-11-17 17:00:00 where update_date =2010-11-16 17:00:00';
    fetch next from cur_tables into info;
    end loop;


return re;
end; $$

language plpgsql;

select test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `execute format` to simplify your update statement.

To check if the update statement modified a value of even single row, you may use 
`ROW_COUNT`  `DIAGNOSTICS`

```
create or replace function test() returns text as $$
declare 
  cur RECORD;
  ct int;
  re text default '';
begin

for cur in ( select  table_name FROM information_schema.tables 
             WHERE table_schema = 'xyz' )
LOOP
    EXECUTE format( 'update xyz.%I set update_date = %L where update_date = %L',
                     cur.table_name,'2010-11-17 17:00:00','2010-11-16 17:00:00') ;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS ct = ROW_COUNT; --get number of rows affected by the 
                                --previous statement.

  IF ct > 0 THEN
    re := re|| ',' ||cur.table_name;
  END IF;

END LOOP;

return trim(BOTH ','  from re);
end; $$

language plpgsql;
```

On a side note, instead of returning a comma separated string of updated tables, it is preferable to return an `array` instead.